# How should I name the language data files?

Tags: spoken-languages

Recently I decided to add some translations to my program.
I wonder how I should name the language files?

1. in the culture's name of the language (example: english = en, french = fr, italian = it, etc...)
2. in the name of the language [in english] (example: english = english, french = french, italian = italian, etc..)

I know you'll choose the second way because you dont have to detect which filename it is because both have the same name.
But the problem is this - I show the name of the languages in its langauge (example: english = english, french = française, italian = italiano, etc..)
so I still need to detect which filename it is.

The main question is which way I should choose? the name of the language in english or the culture name? and why?...

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use the language code, for instance: US english (en-us) and so on.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_code

That way you can get the country and the language.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533052(v=vs.85).aspx

Have you considered this option?

Comment: +1 for using ISO standards

Comment: Alright. I will use you way. I just got one question related to you answer, I found all the specific culture names for my languages except for one > Haitian Creole. I cant find the specific or neutral culture name of it.. do you know what's the culture of it?

Comment: @Ron are you wearing your hat? :D okok that was lame... the language code is `hat`  http://www.sil.org/iso639-3/documentation.asp?id=hat  Regards

Comment: @eestein, indeed it was lame, but still I laughed. anyway this is the netural identifier / global identifier. I need specific culture name (for C#)...

Comment: @Ron Ok, well... it seems you'll have to create your own. Check this link(the answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390119/cultureinfo-haitian-creole-and-net-3-5-on-asp-net-mvc  this is the right way to do it. Hope it helps. Best regards.

Comment: well, I am not going to write it on my own because I basicly needed it for the monthcalendar control. since Haitian Creole close to french, I'll use fr-FR culture for it. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Ron this seems to be the only solution, if you really don't need that use fr. You can always use that code to inherit from fr-FR and create your new CultureInfo changing only what you need. Anyway, good luck.